# Removing superfluous complex types in XML Schema using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xsd

I've received a set of XML Schemas which contain "superfluous" complex types and I'm looking for a way to remove them using XSLT.

The schemas (see below) have a number of `<xsd:element name="ElementX" type="ComplexTypeX">` tags, each which reference a complex type.  Each complex type inherits from a base type in another schema (Datatypes.xsd), however does nothing to extend or restrict the type - hence being rather pointless!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="..." xmlns:xsd="..." xmlns="...">
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="Datatypes.xsd" />

  <xsd:complexType name="ComplexType1">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="ActualType1" />
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="ElementName1" type="ComplexType1" />

  <xsd:complexType name="ComplexType2">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="ActualType2" />
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="ElementName2" type="ComplexType2" />

  ...
 </xsd:schema>
```

I'm trying (but not getting very far...) to write an XSLT transform to:

- Replace the type of each element with the corresponding complex type's base type.  E.g. the type of ElementName1 above would become ActualType1.
- Remove the entire complexType from the output.

Producing output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="..." xmlns:xsd="..." xmlns="...">
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="Datatypes.xsd" />

  <xsd:element name="ElementName1" type="ActualType1" />

  <xsd:element name="ElementName2" type="ActualType2" />
  .
  .
  .
 </xsd:schema>
```

At the moment all the complexType elements don't alter the base type in any way so it is safe to perform the replacement.  However, if in future, some of the complexType elements were changed to restrict or extend their base type (and have meaningful use), I would only like to perform the replacement/removal of the remaining superfluous types.  Though I realise this will increase the complexity of the XSLT somewhat.

Background:  The schemas have come from a third party and unfortunately I don't have any control of their production.  I suspect the extra layer of complex types is present due to tooling used to produce the schemas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying (but not getting very far...) to write an XSLT transform
>   to:
>
> - Replace the type of each element with the corresponding complex type's base type. E.g. the type of ElementName1 above would become
>     ActualType1.
> - Remove the entire complexType from the output.

These two could be achieved by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="complex" match="xsd:complexType" use="@name" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- replace element type -->
<xsl:template match="xsd:element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('complex', @type)/xsd:simpleContent/xsd:extension/@base"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove complexType -->
<xsl:template match="xsd:complexType"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am afraid I did not understand this part:

> However in the case some of the complexType elements were changed to
>   restrict or extend their base type (and have some meaningful use), I
>   would like to add a check for this before performing the
>   replacement/removal.

Comment: I've revised the second part of my question - I'm wondering if its possible to detect whether a complexType is "superfluous" in XSLT and then only perform the replacement/removal if it is.  A complexType could be defined as superfluous if it contains only a simpleContent element which in turn contains an extension element specifying a base attribute; there must be no other child elements or attributes.  Though I realise this increases the complexity somewhat!  Thank you very much for your answer above.

Comment: @jonnyr I suggest you expand your example (input and output) to show all possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- anything not otherwise matched gets copied -->

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="literal"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="attribute-filter">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="literal"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="literal">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- in mode 'attribute-filter', 'name' and 'type' attributes transform to nothing -->
  <xsl:template match="@name|@type" mode="attribute-filter">
    <!-- transforms to nothing -->
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- keep only meaningful extension types -->
  <xsl:template match="/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[./xsd:simpleContent/xsd:extension]">
    <xsl:if test="boolean(./xsd:simpleContent/xsd:extension/node())">
      <!-- a bona fide extension -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="literal"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- else it transforms to nothing -->
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- patch up element declarations where necessary -->
  <xsl:template match="xsd:element[@type]">
    <xsl:variable name="typename" select="@type" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[@name = $typename]/xsd:simpleContent)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="literal"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="boolean(/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[@name = $typename]/xsd:simpleContent/xsd:restriction)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="literal"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="boolean(/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[@name = $typename]/xsd:simpleContent/xsd:extension/node())">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="literal"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@name" />
          <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[@name = $typename]/xsd:simpleContent/xsd:extension/@base"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="attribute-filter"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That supposes that the unwanted complexType declarations all use the "extension" alternative for simple content, as in the example, but it could be extended to also handle other unwanted types as well.

Comment: Contrary to the declaration, this is a XSLT 2.0 stylesheet. I am also puzzled by the result, since the element types remain unchanged.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I updated the XSL version, thanks.  I am uncertain what you mean by element types remaining unchanged, though.  Some do, and some don't, depending on whether the referenced type is a trivial derivation.  (More specifically, depending on whether the referenced type has simple content and is a trivial extension of its base type.)  This is as jonnyr requested, though he may want to tweak the criteria for which types get stripped.

Comment: I thought the given example should produce the given output - but I could easily be wrong about that, since I've lost track of what OP wants.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I claim that the stylesheet I provided will transform the input given in the question to the form specified in the question.  I'm still not seeing why you think otherwise.  This stylesheet will also *avoid* stripping non-trivial derived types, as is also requested (as a future consideration).

Comment: Your output is `<xsd:element name="ElementName1" type="ComplexType1"/>`. I thought the output should be `<xsd:element name="ElementName1" type="ActualType1" />`. I am quite sure that *was* the intended output before OP revised his question. As I said, I am  not sure what he wants now, as he has not responded to my request for clarifications.

Comment: @michael.hor257k you are right.  There were bugs in some of my XPath expressions, now fixed.  I also updated the stylesheet to be XSL 1.0 compliant, and so marked it.  The main differences there are handling of `mode` attributes and switching out `element()` node tests for `node()` node tests.  The latter opens it up a bit to fail to recognize type derivations as being trivial, but it will still work fine for the example input.